# Add a variable to each value in a string column using Pandas

Tags: pandas, string, variables, append

I have a dataframe beheerobjecten:

```
                  Specifieke_omschrijving_beheerobject Systeemdeelnummer
0    Weg, 4,300 tm 16,765 KP Zaandam - Purmerend Noord  007-0010-R
25   Weg, 16,765 tm 34,032 Purmerend Noord - Hoorn ...  007-0020-R
862       Weg, 50,212 tm 64,565 Middenmeer - Den Oever  007-0040-R
```

With the following code I try add a variable to each element in the dataframe:

```
count = 1
while count < len(beheerobjecten):
    beheerobjecten["Systeemdeelnummer"] = beheerobjecten["Systeemdeelnummer"].apply(lambda x: f"{x}.{count}")
    count += 1
```

I get the following output:

```
                  Specifieke_omschrijving_beheerobject Systeemdeelnummer
0    Weg, 4,300 tm 16,765 KP Zaandam - Purmerend Noord    007-0010-R.1.2
25   Weg, 16,765 tm 34,032 Purmerend Noord - Hoorn ...    007-0020-R.1.2
862       Weg, 50,212 tm 64,565 Middenmeer - Den Oever    007-0040-R.1.2
```

However, I try to obtain this output:

```
                 Specifieke_omschrijving_beheerobject Systeemdeelnummer
0    Weg, 4,300 tm 16,765 KP Zaandam - Purmerend Noord  007-0010-R.1
25   Weg, 16,765 tm 34,032 Purmerend Noord - Hoorn ...  007-0020-R.2
862       Weg, 50,212 tm 64,565 Middenmeer - Den Oever  007-0040-R.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it :

```
ser = beheerobjecten["Systeemdeelnummer"].astype(bool).cumsum().astype(str)
​
#another variant
#ser = pd.Series(range(1, len(beheerobjecten)+1), dtype="str", index=beheerobjecten.index)
​
beheerobjecten["Systeemdeelnummer"] = beheerobjecten["Systeemdeelnummer"].str.cat(ser, sep=".")
```

​
Output :

```
print(beheerobjecten)

                   pecifieke_omschrijving_beheerobject Systeemdeelnummer
0    Weg, 4,300 tm 16,765 KP Zaandam - Purmerend Noord      007-0010-R.1
25   Weg, 16,765 tm 34,032 Purmerend Noord - Hoorn ...      007-0020-R.2
862       Weg, 50,212 tm 64,565 Middenmeer - Den Oever      007-0040-R.3
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. Is is also possible to add an if-statement to the code? Thus if 007-0010-R then Add a variable to each value in a string column. The result would be 007-0010-R.1, 007-0010-R.2, 007-0010-R.3, etc. And if 007-0020-R then start again with 1, thus the result would be 007-0020-R.1, 007-0020-R.2, 007-0020-R.3, etc.

Comment: You're welcome. I think in that case, you should use : `ser = beheerobjecten.groupby("Systeemdeelnummer").cumcount().add(1).astype(str)`.